# How to drop patter inside table dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a date column in a dataframe, and the dates are like "2020-03-02" or "2020-02"

I want to remove the "-03-" for the dates like this.
I try:

```
df.Collection_Date.replace(to_replace ='-\d\d-', value = '-', regex = True)
```

but return a like a new dataframe with "0"

how i can remove it?

Comment: Try `df['Collection_Date']=df['Collection_Date'].astype('str').str.replace(r'-\d\d-','')`

Comment: That's wokrs!!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You may convert the column to string type, and then run the regex replacement:

```
df['Collection_Date']=df['Collection_Date'].astype('str').str.replace(r'-\d\d-','')
#                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```